# error for "Texture" sf not loading for cpp framework called sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to load my texture onto my window.... however when I compile in visual studio on windows 10 laptop It says "sf has no member texture" I'm honestly not sure what on earth is going on! for whatever reason its not loading the sf! if you have any ideas please let me know... thanks so much it means a great deal to me! (I have also tried to use "#include" and it has not worked out for me unfortunately)

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>



int main()
{

    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("sheet_1.png"))
    {
        // error...
    }
   
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
   
   
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
       
        
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
           
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including `<SFML/Graphics.hpp>` and some other headers?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php) says to include `Texture.hpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Since sf::Texture is not included in Window.hpp you need to also include **Graphics.hpp** in your project.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```